# iPhone Web App - Doesn't Remember Login

Tags: iphone, session, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1, authorization

Okay,

So I'm running a Rails 3.1 App, with iPhone Support - So I can basically save the web app to my home screen, and it'll have it's own icon + splash screen etc.

I am using Devise to handle logins. Everything works fine in the app.

However, when the user exits to the home screen, and comes back to the app, it no longer remembers their log in session, and so the user must sign in again.

Is there any way around this, so that the app remembers where the user last was / their log in session?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having this same problem and suspected I needed token authentication, but it turns out I just needed to use the Devise [Rememberable](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Rememberable) model.

Here's another Stack Overflow question that shows how to tack it on if you haven't enabled it already:

[How to use Devise: rememberable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810486/how-to-use-devise-rememberable)

I had the model enabled already, but hadn't exposed the checkbox on the sign-in page, so new sessions weren't saved properly. Once I exposed the flag it worked perfectly as an iOS web clip, even after rebooting my phone and the server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Aaaah, I've been searching for solutions to this for ages! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I was banging my head against the wall too. I also discovered that if you have private browsing enabled on your iOS device, this solution doesn't work, as Safari won't store the session.