# How to use Devise: rememberable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, remember-me

I'm making a Rails App.
I'd like to implement a check box 'remember me' for users to skip enter password from next time with using Devise:rememberable.but I can't figure out how to implement. 
if you have any idea with this , please show me some sample code for that.

Answer (score 22):

Add the `:rememberable` option in your User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
         :validatable, :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :omniauthable

  # ...

end
```

Create a migration to add the `remember_created_at` column in the table of users

```
class AddRememberCreatedAtToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :remember_created_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

If you're not using the Devise default views, add the checkbox to your view:

```
<%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %>
```

I think that's all you need...

Answer (score 7):

You may encounter issues with rememberable if you write your own authentication strategies. The resource object (e.g. `User`) returned by your authenticate! method needs to be responsible for setting the `resource.remember_me` from the form data. This is normally handled by the parent Authenticable's [validate](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb#L28-L45) method. If you don't use this method, you'll have to set it yourself.